# Loop while no funciona como esperaba

Tags: while

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion y estoy aprendiendo los while loops, intente hacer un while que pidiera mi nombre y al escribirlo mal que pregunte de nuevo, o de lo contrario que un mensaje como si ese es mi nombre y finalizar el loop... pero no me reconoce ningun nombre como verdadero. Que hice mal?

`Este es el codigo:`

````
let input = prompt("Hey guess my name")

while (input !== "Nicolas") {
    console.log(prompt("Wrong name, try again"))
}

console.log("well done, my name is Nicolas")```
````

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, dentro del while tienes que actualizar el valor de la variable. Pon (dentro del while): `input = prompt("Wrong name, try again"); console.log(input);`

Comment: @ArianJM Funciono, muchisimas gracias!! aunque no comprendi bien la logica detras de la actualizacion de la variable

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que parte no comprendiste bien? si no cambias la variables, siempre tiene lo mismo...

Answer (score 2):

Buen día, cordial saludo. Debes volver a actualizar el contenido de la variable dentro del while, de lo contrario su valor nunca cambiará y continuará dentro del loop

```
let input = prompt("Hey guess my name");

while (input !== "Nicolas") {
    input = prompt("Wrong name, try again"));
    console.log(input);
}

console.log("well done, my name is Nicolas");
```